# how do i access a specific point of an array form another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i was wondering, if i make a method that returns an array. how can i late on access a specific point in that array in the main or another method?

for instance:

```
public static int[] deleteElement(int[]thing, int target){
 int[]newThing;

 newThing=thing;
 int y=0;
 for (int i=0; i<thing.length; i++){
   if (thing[i]==target){
     newThing[y]=thing[i+1];}
   y++;
   }

 return newThing;

 }



 public static int test(int[]someArray){


   //here how can i access newThing[i]? 

   }
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: ??? You access it.  What is the problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Is the other method a member of the same class? Is it the caller of deleteElement()? When do you want to access the array? and is the index to access known?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass the array to another method you do it like:

```
int [] myArray  = yourClass.deleteElement(thing, target)
yourClass.test(myArray);
```

If you are trying to access it, then you do it the same way you assign it:

```
elementYouWantToAccess = 2 //or 3, or 6, or whatever element you want
someArray[elementYouWantToAccess];
```

Technically, you could say:

`someArray[1]; //this would access the element at position 1`.

All you are doing with `i` is listing an element position. Arrays are accessed by choosing a position.

If you don't know the exact element you want, you can iterate over the entire array like so:

```
public static int test(int[]someArray){

  for(int i=0; ii < someArray.length; i++){
      if(someArray[i] == someCondition){
      //do something to someArray[i]
      }
  }

}
```

Until you find the element you want, then assign it to a variable, or do whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `deleteElement(int[]thing, int target)`, which returns an `int[]`. You do not have access to `newThing` outside of `deleteElement(int[]thing, int target)`, since it is declared inside of the method. So:

```
int[] list = deleteElement(ra,target); //list = newThing
list[0], list[1], ...
```

So in order to access elements in the array from outside of the method, you must assign the returned array to something in your class/method and then operate on that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are really asking is how you can operate on subarrays of an array.  After all, you know how to access particular elements: the `a[i]` notation.

There are bulk methods class you can use: `Array.copy`, `Array.copyOfRange`, and `System.arrayCopy`.  But even with those methods, you're doing too much work, especially if you have to delete a few items in an array.  The way you are doing things might be an O(N^2) operation.  Use lists instead.

```
public static Integer[] deleteElement(int[] array, int valueToDelete){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n: array) {
        if (n != valueToDelete) {
            list.add(n);
        }
    }
    return Arrays.toArray(new int[0]);
}
```

But even that is problematic.  You should probably use some type of `List` in the first place, and since you are deleting in the middle, you probably want a `LinkedList`.

```
public static <T> void deleteValue(List<T> list, T value) {
    for (Iterator<T>it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (value.equals(it.next()) {
            it.delete();
        }
    }
}
```